# troubleshooting an invalid syntax error when using pip install

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install `git fat` using python `pip`

However, I am getting an 'invalid syntax' error below:

I've tried lots of things but cannot seem to figure it out.

Appreciate any ideas?

```
sudo pip install git-fat --user
--proxy=http://proxy-chain.intel.com:911/

Collecting git-fat   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d9/83/2b8fe278813c4fe32d4eda87a4981f4258da51aaaffa56e769255c95ca40/git-fat-0.5.0.tar.gz
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-o49cc8aj/git-fat/setup.py", line 18, in <module>
        from git_fat import __version__
      File "/tmp/pip-install-o49cc8aj/git-fat/git_fat/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from .git_fat import *  # noqa
      File "/tmp/pip-install-o49cc8aj/git-fat/git_fat/git_fat.py", line 1093
        if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] in [c + 'version' for c in '', '-', '--']:
                                                                          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-o49cc8aj/git-fat/
```

Comment: It appears that the library does not support Python 3. This is valid in Python 2, but not 3.

Comment: I have python 2 and 3 installed, how do install it for python 2? Thank you